Five Islands/Five Points Theorems (Reference Request)
Does anyone have a modern reference for the Five Islands Theorem of Ahlfors and/or the Five Points Theorem of Lappan?  I know that there are proofs of the Five Islands that don't involve the Ahlfors-Bers Theory (I think using normal families and the main Nevanlinna theorems), but when I last looked I couldn't find it.  I couldn't track down a reasonable proof of the Lappan at all.
The only book I've found that covers Five Islands was Hayman's book on Meromorphic Functions, but he uses the full Ahlfors-Bers Theory which is just not presentable to students.  If a proof uses basic facts about quasiconformal maps that's fine, but I'd prefer to dodge the Measurable Riemann Mapping Theorem/solution of Beltrami equations.
As an aside, I haven't found a good student reference for the MRMT either.  The Ahlfors lecture series book on quasiconformal mappings is kind of a joke as a teaching tool; I could use recommendations for the foundations of quasiconformal mapping theory as well.  Lecture notes are totally fine.
